# VS code extension FTP-Sync: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp

First of all: I can only speak English to a limited extent and have my text translated, which should not be a problem but can sometimes lead to misunderstandings.

I used to use MS Visual Studio. However, I need a source code editor for my web programming, with which I can edit files directly on the web server via FTP. The functionated to VS 2017, but from version 2019 direct FTP access is impossible, and now I was looking for an alternative.

I came across VS Code, for which there are numerous extensions that promise this function. I tried several (FTP-Sync, FTP-Simple, SFTP, FTP-kr etc.) but I cannot access my FTP server. However, other programs, such as web browsers or Windows Explorer, can do this. Incidentally, I tried it on several computers and also tried a public FTP server, always with the same result.

I also disabled the computer's firewall, but it still doesn't work, so that's not why.

Here is my configuration file for the VS code extension FTP-Sync for the public FTP server:

```json
{
    "remotePath": "./",
    "host": "ftp://ftp.rz.uni-wuerzburg.de/",
    "username": "anonymous",
    "password": "email  @gmail.com",
    "port": 21,
    "secure": true,
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "uploadOnSave": false,
    "passive": true,
    "debug": true,
    "privateKeyPath ": null,
    "passphrase": null,
    "agent": null,
    "allow": [],
    "ignore": [
        "\\.vscode",
        "\\.git",
        "\\.DS_Store"
    ],
    "generatedFiles": {
        "extensionsToInclude": [
            ""
        ],
        "path": ""
    }
}
```

As soon as I have the saved one and then try to start the synchronization, I receive the following message:

> Error: Ftp-sync: sync error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ftp://ftp.rz.uni-wuerzburg.de/

Why is this and what can I do to make the synchronization work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ftp://ftp.rz.uni-wuerzburg.de/` is a *URL*.

A `host` (name) is just the `ftp.rz.uni-wuerzburg.de`.